# How do I update my resume when a new contractor company has been hired to replace old contractor

Tags: resume

**Background**:
For the past couple years I have been an onsite contractor for a U.S. Federal Agency. The company that has employed me for the past couple years is at the end of their contract and will not be bidding on the follow-on contract. I have been hired by another contracting company to continue working on the tasks I've been doing at this agency for the past couple years. Essentially nothing has changed in my day to day since being hired by this new contracting company.

**Question**: How should I reflect these changes on my resume when the only things that have changed are that I make more money and there is a different company signing my paychecks?

Comment: List new employer and include the usual stuff about what you do for that employ. And simply add that this is a continuation of the project you on for the old employer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, Shoppers list the Client company, with a tag to indicate that this was a Contract position, as opposed to Direct employment.

For example, from memory, my resume contains something like:

```
Jan 1984 - Aug 1987:  General Dynamics Corporation, Fort Worth Division, Fort Worth TX.  (Contract)
```

Nobody particularly cares who the contract firm (Shop) was.  They care that you worked for SomeUSFederalAgency, between such-and-such dates, doing this-and-that.

Comment: Somebody might care if the contract shop is large enough. I just caution the author not to reveal any information about their job that is sensitive.

Comment: Going by that you just posted, I do believe you worked with my dad at some stage.